# Jquery validation with data-site-key and secret-key

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I have the following problem
When I use jquery validation the captcha checking does not work
What could be the reason

Then if I try to display:
console.log("Value ", recaptchaResponse);
I have an empty value why?

```
<div class="g-recaptcha margins-captcha center" data-sitekey="My-Site-Key"
                    id="reCaptcha" name="captcha"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();

    console.log("Value ", recaptchaResponse);

    $('#formSignup').validate({
        
        rules: {
           captcha: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "/signup/checkCaptcha",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        recaptchaResponse
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

```
public function checkCaptcha()
{
    if(isset($_POST['recaptchaResponse'])){
        $secretKey = "MY_SECRET_KEY";

        $check = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secretKey.'&response='.$_POST['recaptchaResponse']);

        $answer = json_decode($check);   
        
        if($answer->success==false){
            echo "CONFIRM THAT YOU ARE NOT A BOT";
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: How could there possibly be a captcha response already, when you execute this directly in `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formSignup').validate({
        rules: {
           captcha: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "/signup/checkCaptcha",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        recaptchaResponse: grecaptcha.getResponse()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```